# Choose the longest strings between 2 "almost duplicates" in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I want to clean my DataFrame so I started to remove duplicates with `df=df.drop_duplicates()`

But now I am facing some "almost duplicates" like for example:

```
      A                    B
0  football game           13
1  football game Legend    20
```

As a rule of thumb I would like to keep the longest among the aliases. For instance here:

```
      A                    B
1  football game Legend    20
```

EDIT: I added a length column

Comment: What are your rules for "almost duplicates"? Are the ones with the first word as equal?

Comment: By almost duplicates, I mean that the strings usually start the same way (by one or two words and then end differently). When this occurs, I would like to choose the longest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: since the example you've given has changed, depending on the size of your dataset, you may be better off defining your `unique_words` explicitly: e.g. `unique_words = ['foo', 'pro']`, or in the new example `unique_words = ['football game']`.

Then the loop changes a little. Get `matches` from original dataframe (rows that begin with `word`), and use this to extract the longest.

```
idcs = []
for word in unique_words:
    matches = df['A'].str.match(word)
    longest_idx = df[matches]['A'].str.len().sort_values().index[-1]
    idcs.append(longest_idx)
```

---

Assuming your condition for "almost duplicate" is that the first word is the same, you can do as follows:

Split the entries, extract the first words, then the unique words:

```
split_words = df['A'].str.split()
first_words = split_words.str[0]
unique_words = first_words.unique()
```

Loop through these unique strings and add the longest:

```
idcs = []
for word in unique_words:
    longest_idx = df[first_words ==
                     word]['A'].str.len().sort_values().index[-1]
    idcs.append(longest_idx)
```

And you're left with the two you (originally) wanted:

```
df.iloc[idcs]

                      A
2     foo tball player
4  pro gramming skills
```

Comment: .str.len().sort_values().index[-1] was what I was looking for, thank you!